# Different Bootstappers for Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, caliburn.micro

I have seen an override of the Caliburn.Micro bootstrapper that facilitates the use of MEF on the [Caliburn.Micro site](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper&referringTitle=Documentation). The override is

```
public class MefBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private CompositionContainer container;

    public MefBootstrapper() { Start(); }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = CompositionHost.Initialize(
            new AggregateCatalog(
                AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()
                )
            );

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue(container);
        container.Compose(batch);
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
        var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);
        if (exports.Any())
            return exports.First();
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
    }
}
```

Now, I have read about Caliburn.Micros `SimpleContainer` for IOC

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
     SimpleContainer container;

     public AppBootstrapper() { Start(); }

     protected override void Configure()
     {  
         container = new SimpleContainer();
         container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
         container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
         container.PerRequest<IShell, ShellViewModel>();
     }

     protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
     {
         var instance = container.GetInstance(service, key);
         if (instance != null)
             return instance;
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not locate any instances.");
     }

     protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
     {
         return container.GetAllInstances(service);
     }

     protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
     {
         container.BuildUp(instance);
     }

     protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
     {
         DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
     }
}
```

I have read [MSDN docs on CompositionContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I am confused as to how to build the bootstrapper to configure *both* IOC *and* MEF support. Is this just a matter of combining the code in the two bootstrappers above and if so what do I return from the `GetInstance` override?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: MEF *is* an implementation of inversion of control. I doubt you want both to co-exist.

Comment: But MEF is an add-in model is it not? It enable extensiblity of application as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAF is probably what you are thinking of... It is also described in that msdn link.  And the differences between the 2.

As Steve pointed out you probably don't want to have both SimpleContainer and MEF co-existing that and I am sure the IoC static class would probably have a heart attack.  I actually would use MEF for larger projects for doing DI/IoC.  It can be a help or a burden at times due its power.  one of the limitations MEF has is open generics it dies horribly when trying do open generics, supposedly there are external projects that help mitigate.

there were a couple of projects around that integrate MAF with MEF